# What's a way I can save a trigger "template" in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Let's say I created a table `test_table` in development just to test a trigger, this trigger would then be reused in many other tables (future and existing).

So I code the trigger, test it, all good! But at the moment, if I want to replicate it, I will have to copy it from `test_table`'s triggers and edit it.

So if someone deletes the table accidentally, the trigger is gone, and I don't have it saved nowhere else. Or if I just want to delete random test tables in our database, I can't.

What's a recommended way to save a trigger as a "template" **in oracle**? So I can reuse it in other tables and have it not be dependant of a random test table, or any table.

Comment: Version control like Git/SVN

Comment: Make sure that someone "accidentally" dropping your table (or whole database, for that matter) can't cause you to lose your work. That's partly what version control is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can keep a copy of your `TRIGGER` SQLText.

Here's a few examples.

**In Version Control:**
You can use any of the many version control tools to maintain a versioned history for any code you like, including SQL, PL/SQL, etc. You can rewind time, view differences over time, track changes to the template, even allow concurrent development.

**As a Function:**
If you want the template to live in the database, you can create a `FUNCTION` (or `PACKAGE`)that takes as parameters the target `USER` and `TABLE`, and it replaces the `USER` and `TABLE` values in its template to generate the `SQLTEXT` required to create or replace the template `TRIGGER` on the target `TABLE`.  You can make it `EDITIONABLE` as needed.

**In a Table:**
You can always just create a `TABLE` that holds template `TRIGGER` SQLText as a `CLOB` or `VARCHAR2`.  It would need to be somewhere where it isn't likele to be "randomly" deleted, though.  You can `AUDIT` changes to the `TABLE`'s data, to see the template change over time.  Oracle has tons of auditing options.

**In the logs:**
You can just log (all) `DDL` out.  If you `ENABLE_DDL_LOGGING`, the log xml will have a copy of every `DDL` statement, categorized, along with when and where it came from.

Comment: I guess the function is the best way for storing it in oracle, I really wish I could store an anonymous trigger